# Calculate a mean per day per sample, then add a line of best fit

Tags: r

**My Question:**

How do I calculate the average (mean) per sample A, B, C per day (3 separate to 5) and then add a line of best fit through the mean from one day to the next?

I wanted to add this to a dot plot (ggplot2 geom_point) example of data is below... R script used below data.

Data below:

```
Day     Sample  Measurement
3   A   0.648
3   A   0.661
3   A   0.65
3   A   0.594
3   A   0.548
3   A   0.653
3   A   0.648
3   A   0.672
3   A   0.661
3   A   0.66
3   A   0.647
3   A   0.629
3   A   0.691
3   A   0.534
3   A   0.567
3   A   0.634
3   A   0.579
3   B   0.689
3   B   0.598
3   B   0.658
3   B   0.662
3   B   0.599
3   B   0.678
3   B   0.65
3   B   0.617
3   B   0.673
3   B   0.67
3   B   0.666
3   B   0.595
3   B   0.604
3   B   0.59
3   B   0.569
3   B   0.614
3   C   0.624
3   C   0.623
3   C   0.606
3   C   0.66
3   C   0.623
3   C   0.669
3   C   0.642
3   C   0.658
3   C   0.645
3   C   0.653
3   C   0.501
3   C   0.552
3   C   0.663
3   C   0.589
3   C   0.602
5   A   0.811
5   A   0.822
5   A   0.811
5   A   0.824
5   A   0.773
5   A   0.823
5   A   0.815
5   A   0.819
5   A   0.754
5   A   0.81
5   A   0.796
5   A   0.818
5   A   0.797
5   A   0.811
5   A   0.812
5   A   0.817
5   A   0.821
5   B   0.827
5   B   0.798
5   B   0.819
5   B   0.81
5   B   0.826
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.805
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.825
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.816
5   B   0.814
5   B   0.823
5   B   0.81
5   B   0.823
5   B   0.762
5   B   0.825
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.825
5   B   0.812
```

R Code for ggplot:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=Day, y=Fv.Fm..XE..Mean)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour= Sample), 
  position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.75 , jitter.width=0.250)) +
  # geom_line(aes(colour=Sample), 
  # position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.75)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c(3, 5, 7, 10, 14)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.3 , 1.0))
p2
ggsave("p2.jpg")
```

Comment: mean line won't be informative. Try using `geom_smooth`

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the mean for each `Sample` and `Day`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

data1 <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

mean_data1 <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(Day, Sample) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Measurement, na.rm = TRUE))
mean_data1

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   Day [?]
#>     Day Sample  Mean
#>   <int> <fct>  <dbl>
#> 1     3 A      0.628
#> 2     3 B      0.633
#> 3     3 C      0.621
#> 4     5 A      0.808
#> 5     5 B      0.815
```

Then plot all Measurement, `facet_grid` by Sample. Linear lines are added using `geom_smooth`. `stat_poly_eq` function from `ggpmisc` package is used for displaying equation & R2. Finally, we plot the `Mean` values.

```r
p2 <- ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = Day, y = Measurement)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour= Sample), 
             alpha = 0.7,
             position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.75, 
                                             jitter.width=0.250)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(3, 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.3 , 1.0))

formula <- y ~ x

p2 + 
  facet_grid(~ Sample) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = formula, se = FALSE) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")), 
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = "top",
               formula = formula, parse = TRUE, size = 4) +
  geom_point(data = mean_data1, aes(Day, Mean, color = "Mean"), 
             size = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Data used:

```r
txt <- "Day     Sample  Measurement
3   A   0.648
3   A   0.661
3   A   0.65
3   A   0.594
3   A   0.548
3   A   0.653
3   A   0.648
3   A   0.672
3   A   0.661
3   A   0.66
3   A   0.647
3   A   0.629
3   A   0.691
3   A   0.534
3   A   0.567
3   A   0.634
3   A   0.579
3   B   0.689
3   B   0.598
3   B   0.658
3   B   0.662
3   B   0.599
3   B   0.678
3   B   0.65
3   B   0.617
3   B   0.673
3   B   0.67
3   B   0.666
3   B   0.595
3   B   0.604
3   B   0.59
3   B   0.569
3   B   0.614
3   C   0.624
3   C   0.623
3   C   0.606
3   C   0.66
3   C   0.623
3   C   0.669
3   C   0.642
3   C   0.658
3   C   0.645
3   C   0.653
3   C   0.501
3   C   0.552
3   C   0.663
3   C   0.589
3   C   0.602
5   A   0.811
5   A   0.822
5   A   0.811
5   A   0.824
5   A   0.773
5   A   0.823
5   A   0.815
5   A   0.819
5   A   0.754
5   A   0.81
5   A   0.796
5   A   0.818
5   A   0.797
5   A   0.811
5   A   0.812
5   A   0.817
5   A   0.821
5   B   0.827
5   B   0.798
5   B   0.819
5   B   0.81
5   B   0.826
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.805
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.825
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.816
5   B   0.814
5   B   0.823
5   B   0.81
5   B   0.823
5   B   0.762
5   B   0.825
5   B   0.821
5   B   0.825
5   B   0.812"
```

Created on 2018-03-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks. I have found one that worked.  I also got help adding standard error bars above and below the mean. geom_point and geom_errorbar were useful with the library(ggplot2) library(dplyr).   geom_errorbar(data = data1Summary,                                  jitter dodge was very useful. Thanks.  Having all the data sets on the one graph was useful too.
                aes(y = mean_mean,
                    ymin = mean_mean-mean_se,
                    ymax = mean_mean+mean_se),